# error while trying to push database to heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, push

I am trying to do a

```
$heroku db:push
```

this is the error I get

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:138:in `union': can't convert Array into
String (TypeError)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:138
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.9/lib/taps/multipart.rb:2
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.9/lib/taps/data_stream.rb:2
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
         ... 8 levels...
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.9.11/lib/heroku/command.rb:20:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.9.11/bin/heroku:13
        from C:/Ruby/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby/bin/heroku:19
```

It is a brand new MySQL development database, the taps gem is installed.  I have pushed this same database to multiple other heroku apps, those have all been deleted.

Comment: Can you provide some context for this problem please? Is this a database you've pulled from Heroku before or a brand new one from your development environment? What format is it in currently? Have you installed the taps gem?

Comment: he appears to have taps-0.3.9 installed (judging from the stack trace) - but yeah, it looks like a bit more info would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the `version` of rack gem?

try making it rack (1.0.1)

```
i.e gem uninstall rack <version number>
then gem install rack 1.0.1
```

Hope this helps,

Regards,

Saurabh